# Why i'm getting time out exception and how should i handle this when using httpwebrequest to download a file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the code:

```
HttpWebRequest request;
        int currentIndex = 0;
        void fileDownloadRadar(string uri, string fileName)
        {
            if (splash != null)
            {
                if (!splash.IsDisposed)
                    splash.UpdateProgressBar(0);
            }
            /*_request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
            _request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            _request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            _responseAsyncResult = _request.BeginGetResponse(ResponseCallback, null);*/
            request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            long contentLength = response.ContentLength;
            if (response.ContentType == "")
            {
                Logger.Write("ContentType is Empty download was not fine !!!!!");
            }
            if ((response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ||
                response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved ||
                response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect) &&
                response.ContentType.StartsWith("image", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                Logger.Write("ContentType is not empty meaning download is fine");
                using (Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead;
                    do
                    {
                        bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        currentIndex += bytesRead;
                        double percentage = (double)currentIndex / contentLength;
                        if (splash != null)
                        {
                            if (!splash.IsDisposed)
                                splash.UpdateProgressBar((int)(percentage * 100));
                        }
                        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    } while (bytesRead != 0);
                    if (splash != null)
                    {
                        if (!splash.IsDisposed)
                        {
                            splash.UpdateProgressBar(100);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                timer3.Start();
            }
            if (splash == null)
                FinishWebRequest();
        }
```

The exception is on the line:

```
bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

The exception is: WebException

The operation has timed out

I see that when the exception happened the variable bytesRead value is 1360
And buffer values is 4096

```
System.Net.WebException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The operation has timed out.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
       at mws.Form1.fileDownloadRadar(String uri, String fileName) in d:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\Form1.cs:line 914
  InnerException:
```

Line 914 is:

```
bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Maybe i should put try and catch somewhere ?

My code is downloading a file then a timer is running when the timer count 5 minutes it's downloading the same file again and so on over again nonstop every 5 minutes i'm calling this method to download the file.

EDIT this is my code after changed it according to the answers:

```
HttpWebRequest request;
        int currentIndex = 0;
        void fileDownloadRadar(string uri, string fileName)
        {
            if (splash != null)
            {
                if (!splash.IsDisposed)
                    splash.UpdateProgressBar(0);
            }
            try
            {
                request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
                request.Timeout = 10000;
                request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    long contentLength = response.ContentLength;
                    if (response.ContentType == "")
                    {
                        Logger.Write("ContentType is Empty download was not fine !!!!!");
                    }
                    if ((response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ||
                        response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved ||
                        response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect) &&
                        response.ContentType.StartsWith("image", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        Logger.Write("ContentType is not empty meaning download is fine");
                        using (Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                        using (Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                            int bytesRead;
                            do
                            {
                                bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                currentIndex += bytesRead;
                                double percentage = (double)currentIndex / contentLength;
                                if (splash != null)
                                {
                                    if (!splash.IsDisposed)
                                        splash.UpdateProgressBar((int)(percentage * 100));
                                }
                                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            } while (bytesRead != 0);
                            if (splash != null)
                            {
                                if (!splash.IsDisposed)
                                {
                                    splash.UpdateProgressBar(100);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        timer1.Stop();
                        timer3.Start();
                    }
                    if (splash == null)
                        FinishWebRequest();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
                {
                    Logger.Write(ex.Status.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

But after it was working fine for maybe an hour or so and downloaded the file few times now i got the exception time out again:

The operation has timed out

This time on the line:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
```

And the exception message:

```
System.Net.WebException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The operation has timed out
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at mws.Form1.fileDownloadRadar(String uri, String fileName) in d:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\Form1.cs:line 899
  InnerException:
```

I changed the response and using the using
Also added: request.Timeout = 10000;
And added also try and catch.

Comment: You need to call response.Close() after you are done with the response stream.

Comment: Ok i added a response.Close(); right after this line: } while (bytesRead != 0); and i also added in the top of the method after the WebRequest.Create(uri); i added: request.Timeout = 10000; but what will happen if the operation was longer then 10 seconds ? Then it will throw the exception again ?

Comment: I just posted an answer - it should not throw timeouts anymore.

Comment: After it was working for about an hour or so now i got this exception of timeout again.

Comment: In the try catch it didn't get to the catch it first throw the exception only when i did continue it went to the catch. And in the catch when i did continue the program continue to work. The question again is why the exception show up and how to handle it i guess the try and catch didn't help.

Comment: Maybe i should remove completely the line request.Timeout = 10000;  ?

Answer (score 3):

The timeouts you are seeing are caused by [ServicePointManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  - class that manages the collection of [ServicePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  objects which provides connection management for HTTP connections.

In short, whenever you create a request and the response, the important thing is to call the `Close()` method on your response object. If not, it will prevent any of the connections in the ServicePoint object from being freed, so at some point, after you have made the critical number of request, no additional requests can be served and you will experience the timeouts.

For more in depth information check out this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/05/20/understanding-maxservicepointidletime-and-defaultconnectionlimit.aspx

```
HttpWebRequest req = CreateRequest();
HttpWebResponse res = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
...
res.Close();  //you should always close the response
```

EDIT:

as @Kevin said in the comment, another solution would be to wrap the response in a using statement and that would automatically close the connection:

```
using(HttpWebResponse res = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: DZL - an explanation of the using block would be appropriate here also as it would automatically close the connection.

Answer (score 3):

The first step is to put your code inside try..catch

```
   try
   {
     //code 
   }
   catch (WebException ex)
   {
       if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
       {
           //log your exception
       }
   }
```

Then wrap the web response with a using block because it automatically call close and also dispose the object

```
  using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
  {
      //your code
  }
```

Lastly, I see in your code you have attempted to use asynchronous request, maybe you can consider that if you're dealing with huge files to deal with a timeout issue. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

[System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215488/system-net-webexception-the-operation-has-timed-out)

This may fit for your problem, as it is regarded to a TimeOut Exception.
The most helpful answer relates to:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout.aspx